# C microshell Segfaulting with one argument, but not with two

Tags: c++, unix, pipe

I am working on creating a microshell that will take in input and give me unix system output. I am doing this with a || instead of just | for a pipe. My shell runs fine if I give it two arguments separated by ||, but if I give it just one argument it segfaults. Can anyone help me with this? I have been debugging for hours with no luck. Thank you in advance!

```
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char command[160];
    pid_t pid1 = 1, pid2 = 1;

    cout << "myshell> ";
    cin.getline(command, 160);

    while (strcmp(command, "q") != 0 && strcmp(command, "quit") != 0 && pid1 > 0
            && pid2 > 0)
    {
        char* arg1[6];
        char* arg2[6];
        char path1[21], path2[21];
        int pipefd[2];
        arg1[0] = NULL;
        arg2[0] = NULL;

        getParms(command, arg1, arg2);

        if (pipe(pipefd) < 0)
        {
            perror("Pipe");
            exit(-1);
        }

        pid1 = fork();
        if (pid1 < 0)
        {
            perror("Fork");
            exit(-1);
        }

        if (pid1 == 0)
        {

            if (arg2[0] != NULL)
            {
                close(pipefd[0]);
                close(1);
                dup(pipefd[1]);
                close(pipefd[1]);
            }

            strcpy(path1, "/bin/");
            strcat(path1, arg1[0]);
            if (execvp(path1, arg1) < 0)
            {
                strcpy(path1, "/usr/bin/");
                strncat(path1, arg1[0], strlen(arg1[0]));
                if (execvp(path1, arg1) < 0)
                {
                    cout << "Couldn't execute " << arg1[0] << endl;
                    exit(127);
                }
            }

            if (arg2[0] == NULL)
            { // Parent process
                close(pipefd[0]); //read
                close(pipefd[1]); //write

                waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0); // Waits for child2
                cout << "myshell> ";
                cin.getline(command, 160);
            }
        }

        else if (arg2[0] != NULL)
        {
            pid2 = fork();
            if (pid2 < 0)
            {
                perror("Fork");
                exit(-1);
            }

            if (pid2 == 0)
            {
                close(pipefd[1]);
                close(0);

                dup(pipefd[0]);
                close(pipefd[0]);

                strcpy(path2, "/bin/");
                strncat(path2, arg2[0], strlen(arg2[0]));
                if (execvp(path2, arg2) < 0)
                {
                    strcpy(path2, "/usr/bin/");
                    strncat(path2, arg2[0], strlen(arg2[0]));
                    if (execvp(path2, arg2) < 0)
                    {
                        cout << "Couldn't execute " << arg2[0] << endl;
                        exit(127);
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            { // Parent process
                close(pipefd[0]); //read
                close(pipefd[1]); //write

                waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0); // Waits for child2
                cout << "myshell> ";
                cin.getline(command, 160);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void getParms(char str[], char* args[], char* args2[])
{
    char* index;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    index = strtok(str, " ");

    // While the token isn't NULL or pipe
    while (index != NULL && strstr(index, "||") == NULL)
    {
        args[i] = index;
        index = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    args[i] = (char*) NULL; // makes last element Null

    if (strstr(index, "||") != NULL)
    {
        index = strtok(NULL, " ");
        while (index != NULL)
        {
            args2[j] = index;
            index = strtok(NULL, " ");
            j++;
        }
    }

    args2[j] = (char*) NULL; // makes last element Null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a bit, because you don't include examples of an input that works and one that doesn't.

If you look at this in your debugger, you'll see that if you only give one argument (without a "||"), `index` will be NULL in your call to `strstr` before the second loop.  Since `strstr` does not expect a NULL parameter, the crash results.

Comment: Thank you! examples of working parms would be something like cat info.txt || sort , but using any command but this breaks it

Comment: Is there a way to check for "||" that will accept a NULL?

Comment: @GrapeSoda3 You're overthinking it.  `if (index != NULL && strstr(index, "||") != NULL)`.

Comment: if I run anything with that code, I either get a fork error or a input output error